# Recursive program printing but not returning correct values

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to solve a leetcode problem called word break https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/

Given a non-empty string s and a dictionary wordDict containing a list of non-empty words, determine if s can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words.

I'm able to print the different word breaks that fit the solution but when returning my code always returns None. How can I fix it so that `res` is an array containing the different words in the dictionary that create s

```
import sys; 

class Solution:
    def wordBreak(self, s, wordDict):
        res = self.driver(s, 0, len(s), wordDict, [])
        print(res)

    def driver(self, text, start, end, wordDict, res):
        if text[start:end] == None:    
            return res
        elif text[start:end] in wordDict:
            result = text[start:end]
            res.append(result)
            print(res)
            return self.driver(text, end, len(text), wordDict, res)
        else:
            for i in range(start, end):
                self.driver(text, start, i, wordDict, res)
```

Comment: Why do you even need a class for this? As a side note, `driver` does not return anything in the recursive case.

Comment: @DYZ I think that website expects solutions in a class `Solution` for their code challenges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is common with recursive problems like this, you're making it harder than necessary by not letting the recursion do the work.  Although the solution by @blhsing is elegant (+1), let's work with your design, but simplify it:

```
class Solution:
    def wordBreak(self, s, wordDict):
        return self.wordBreak_recursive(s, 0, len(s), wordDict)

    def wordBreak_recursive(self, s, start, end, wordDict):

        for index in range(start + 1, end + 1):
            if s[start:index] in wordDict and (index == end or self.wordBreak_recursive(s, index, end, wordDict)):
                return True

        return False
```

There is no need to collect the segments in `res` as the requirement is a boolean result as to whether the fitting is possible or not:

```
solver = Solution()

print(solver.wordBreak("leetcode", ["leet", "code"]))
print(solver.wordBreak("applepenapple", ["apple", "pen"]))
print(solver.wordBreak("catsandog", ["cats", "dog", "sand", "and", "cat"]))
```

OUTPUT

```
> python3 test.py
True
True
False
>
```

Similarly, we don't need to find all solutions, just one to qualify.

Finally, If your recursive method returns a value, then any time we call it recursively, we generally need to address that returned value, not ignore it -- even if the recursive method secures a result by modifying a variable in its caller's environment.  Otherwise, perhaps it shouldn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the given string `s` starts with any word in the `wordDict`, and then recursively check if the rest of the string in `s` can be partitioned with words in `wordDict`:

```
class Solution:
    def wordBreak(self, s, wordDict):
        return not s or any(s.startswith(word) and self.wordBreak(s[len(word):], wordDict) for word in wordDict)
```

Comment: There's a subtlety here in that the problem states that `wordBreak` will be "Given a *non-empty* string" but your solution relies on it being given an *empty* string to terminate the recursion and return `True`.  I'm not sure how to to think about that contradiction, but an elegant solution nonetheless (+1).

Comment: Thanks. Since the behavior of the function when given an empty `s` is undefined by the question, I believe that we have the freedom to make it return what's convenient when `s` is empty. Note that I've also simplified the code to make it less verbose.